# Eclipse for PHP, need to know the supporting files?

Tags: php, windows, eclipse

I have download eclipse for php in winodws, i am new to this, can anyone tell me, like how to run a php program in eclipse environment

I need to know the dependencies, i need to install to run  eclipse and also tutorial if possible,

Regards,

RAVI

Answer (score 2):

if you are new to php and/or a php IDE. i would suggest you have a look at netbeans. it's simple and lean in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you new to eclipse or php? If php then i wouldn't start using eclipse, it does to much "magic" you will not learn much and only get confused